# Nativescript angular preventing modal closing on background tap

Tags: angularjs, nativescript

I am pretty new to NativeScript but want to be able to prevent a custom modal that I have created from being closed when a user taps on the background, specifically for Android devices.

I can accomplish this pretty easily when using the provided dialogs from NativeScript i.e. for an action dialog can simply do this by setting `cancelable` to false in the options provided.

```
let options: ActionOptions = {
    title: "Sticky Dialog",
    message: "Will not disappear if background tapped",
    cancelable: false,
    actions: ["Cancel", "OK"]
};

dialogs.action(options).then(result => {
   console.log(result);
});
```

But when showing my custom modal using the `ModalDialogService` there is no such property that can be set in the options, currently I have

```
let modalOptions: ModalDialogOptions = {
    context: {},
    fullscreen: false,
    viewContainerRef: this.vcRef,
};

this.modalService.showModal(DeviceRegistrationComponent, modalOptions)
     .then(result => {
         if (result != null) {
            this.handleDeviceOtpEntry(result.otp);
         }
     });
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? I do not mind having to set the specific native android properties, but cannot seem to be able to get a handle to the actual modal that gets displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so after some trial and error managed to come up with a solution (if there is a better way please let me know)

It seems from looking at the source that if we create a modal dialog using the `ModalDialogService` there is no convenient way to set `cancelable` for android, so instead, in my modal component I listen for the `shownModally` event and once fired, we can then attempt to find the currently displayed fragment, which is created by NativeScript with the tag `dialog`.

Once we have that we can simply set the native property.

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {Page} from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import {ModalDialogParams} from "nativescript-angular";
import * as application from "tns-core-modules/application";
import {isAndroid} from "tns-core-modules/platform";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "app-device-registration",
    templateUrl: "./device.registration.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./device.registration.component.css"]
})
export class DeviceRegistrationComponent {

constructor(private params: ModalDialogParams, private page: Page) {
    this.page.on("shownModally", data => {
        if (isAndroid) {
            let fragmentManger = application.android.foregroundActivity.getFragmentManager();
            let dialogFragment = fragmentManger.findFragmentByTag("dialog");
            if (dialogFragment !== null) {
                dialogFragment.setCancelable(false);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With NativeScript 5.0 I have used this code, add (loaded) event handler to the html file

```
<GridLayout (loaded)="onLoaded($event)">
```

and add this code to your typescript file

```
import { isAndroid } from "platform";

onLoaded(e: any): void {
    if (isAndroid) {
        e.object._dialogFragment.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fast-forward to 2018 and release on NS 4, Brendon's answer isn't working anymore, so here's an updated code snippet, doing the same thing.

```js
export class ModalViewComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(
  private _routerExtensions: RouterExtensions,
  private _activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  private params: ModalDialogParams,
  private frame: Frame) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
  if (this.frame.android) {   
   setTimeout(_ => {
    let activity = this.frame.android.currentActivity, fm = activity.getFragmentManager(), fragment = fm.findFragmentById(0);
    if (fragment) fragment.setCancelable(false)
   },10)
  }
 }
}
```